# Cross platform game developement using Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mobile

How can I release the Android game I just made using unity in iOS too? …I don't have a Mac…Should I buy one? and even if I did, do I need to code again?

Comment: if you dont have mac you cant build for ios . No you should not rewrite for ios . but if you have Android specific functional , native library call and so on. you should specify with preprocessors llike (UNITY_ANDROID,UNITY_IOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work arround could be using VMware or VirtualBox or any virtual machine and run IOS on it if you are really determined and don't want to spend money :)